# postgres function error on excution

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have written a function which fetches the total count of records which satisfy a condition (13 months of records only) .
The query works fine i have tested it seperately but when I execute the query n this function I get an error so i guess it must be some syntax error.

```
    CREATE  OR REPLACE FUNCTION deleteAggTables111(tablename TEXT) RETURNS INTEGER AS $total$
DECLARE
total integer;

BEGIN
 execute 'select count (*)  from  '||tablename||'
where cast(date_dimension_year || '-' || date_dimension_month ||'-' ||date_dimension_day as date) 
between (current_date - interval ''13 months'') and current_date ' into total;        

RETURN total;
END;
 $total$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

the error on calling this function :

**select deleteAggTables111('tablename');**

```
  17:50:55  [SELECT - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 0, SQL State: 42725]  ERROR: operator is not unique: unknown - unknown
  Hint: Could not choose a best candidate operator. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Where: PL/pgSQL function deleteaggtables111(text) line 6 at EXECUTE statement
... 1 statement(s) executed, 0 row(s) affected, exec/fetch time: 0.000/0.000 sec  [0 successful, 0 warnings, 1 errors]
```

Thanks & Regards,
Rajeev

Comment: change `'-'` to `''-''`

Comment: I think I did try that as well....but then it didnt compile

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with ' ' I was not closing the quotes in some places basically it was a syntax issue.

Thanks